# Testing of graceful handling of invalid UTF-8 in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, utf-8, middleware

I'm currently trying to ensure that my rails application handles POST methods with invalid UTF-8 data gracefully (e.g. \xFF) (using rack middleware)

Unfortunately writing tests for this is proving extremely difficult.

One thing I've tried is using Capybara to fill in one of my form fields with invalid UTF-8 and submit, however this causes the following output in the terminal amongst my test output - and it's not being printed by Rails!

> error : string is not in utf-8

Is there another way that a POST containing invalid UTF-8 data can be emulated in order to validate that a 400 error (or similar) is displayed?

NB: I'm trying to avoid having to run against a separate running instance of the application (e.g. using 'curl' against it), but just run directly with Capybara (or similar)

Comment: Hey IAmFledge, did you ever find a solution to this? I was just about to embark on the same course of action when I stumbled across this post.

Comment: Hey @fractious, for the moment we just went with a manual test. If you  do find a good way to automate the testing for this though, please post it on here as an answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try posting a file attachment which contains invalid utf-8 data, although this would also depend on your form itself. However, as you're testing a rather obscure edge-case, you could always create a form that is only accessible in dev/test environments, with the route also only available for testing.

This would at least allow you to target the code that handles the processing of the invalid utf-8 data in a safe, test-only way.

Comment: We've considered the second approach as an option. Not sure it can be done with Capybara though? Would have to be tested against a running instance of the application.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by filling the form with invalid UTF-8? The characters you fill in the form do not have any encoding, they are encoded when the form is sent. This sentence would make sense for some encodings that cannot encode all characters out there but UTF-8 *can*.

If you want to send the byte `\xFF` to the server from a browser, it's as easy as pulling out the developer tools of that browser, editing the form's attributes to `accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"` writing `ÿ` somewhere on the form and pressing send. The `ÿ` will get encoded as a `%FF` which cannot be decoded as UTF-8:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/0KCpa9p.png]

[image]

Comment: Hi Esailija, thanks for your answer. We've been able to manually test the handling, but my question here is around doing it as an automated (probably Capybara) test - rather than manually tweaking stuff in a brower.

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in [this ThoughtBot blog post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/42664369166/fight-back-utf-8-invalid-byte-sequences), this worked for me in a unit test:

```
"hello joel\255".force_encoding('UTF-8')
```

Not sure how you'd convince capybara to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by constructing a post with rack-test as opposed to using capybara.

For example the following request spec (`spec/requests/utf8_spec.rb`):

```ruby
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Invalid UTF-8" do
  it "handles invalid UTF-8 in post data gracefully" do
    post "/users", :user => {:name => "Test \xFF boom"}
  end
end
```

Produces the following when run:

```
1) Invalid UTF-8 handles invalid UTF-8 in post data gracefully
   Failure/Error: post "/users", :user => {:name => "Test \xFF boom"}
   ArgumentError:
     invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
   # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:17:in `create'
   # ./spec/requests/utf8_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```